# Left click not working, right click sporadic

Tags: mouse, tap-to-click

Been having mouse problems on Ubuntu 14.04 latley. First off the left click button stopped responding but I could still tap the mousepad to click. Then that stopped responding so I used a USB mouse which worked but now is also not responding!  On top of that now the right click is only working sometimes... Have run several restarts, updates and upgrades with no joy. Any help? Many thanks In advance. Luke

Answer (score 0):

A stuck CTL, ALT, Windows or Menu key (assuming a Windows marked keyboard) can cause click activity to change meaning (often seeming to do nothing), regardless of hardware source.  Try cleaning the keyboard (method varies on laptops; some have removable keycaps, most don't) to see if that improves the situation.